# Unable to read a file from localhost

Tags: linux, web-applications, webserver

I have created a text file and stored in /var/www/html folder in my local linux machine. When I am trying to access the same file through URL- http://localhost/fileName, page is not loading. I was expecting that the file text should appear in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What webserver are you running? If you're not using something like nginx or apache, or even `python -m SimpleHttpServer`, you're not going to be able to access it via the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnMilo. Apache server was seems to be down. After restarting it, i was able to access the file with HTTP